# Pandas grouping rows based on groupings in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on a problem which has been puzzling me for a while.

A brief explanation would be I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 contains a column x which is made up of individual strings, and column y which is values.

df2 is a single column containing strings. These are the same as df1 column x, however some of them are grouped into strings, but separated by a semi-colon ';'.

What I am trying to do is create another dataframe, which takes df1 and sums up the values in column y, to produce the 'Result' dataframe.

Is there a simple way of doing this in Pandas?

Thank you.

```
df1
   
    x  y 
0  'a' 5
1  'b' 4
2  'c' 9
3  'd' 1
4  'e' 3
5  'f' 3
6  'g' 4
7  'h' 5
8  'i' 6 
9  'j' 6
10 'k' 9

df2

   group
0  'a'
1  'b;h;d' 
2  'e'
3  'f'
4  'g;c;i'
5  'j'
6  'k'


Result
 
  group     y
0  'a'      5
1  'b;h;d'  10
2  'e'      3
3  'f'      3
4  'g;c;i'  19
5  'j'      6
6  'k'      9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.group = df2.group.str.split(";")
df2 = df2.explode("group").merge(df1, left_on="group", right_on="x", how="left")
out = (
    df2.groupby("index")
    .agg({"x": ";".join, "y": "sum"})
    .rename(columns={"x": "group"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   group   y
0      a   5
1  b;h;d  10
2      e   3
3      f   3
4  g;c;i  19
5      j   6
6      k   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be just to add `group` column to df1 from df2 for corresponding value in `x` column of `df1`, then just groupby the newly added column and call sum on `y` column for each group:

```py
df1['group'] = ''
for group in df2['group'].values:
    df1.loc[df1['x'].str[1:-1].isin(list(group)), 'group'] = group
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
df1.groupby('group')['y'].sum()
group
'a'         5
'b;h;d'    10
'e'         3
'f'         3
'g;c;i'    19
'j'         6
'k'         9
Name: y, dtype: int64
```